# How to export grid to XLS in ExtJS4.0

Tags: extjs

Is there a simple way to export a grid data to XLS in ExtJS.

If not I am trying the following way.

I am trying to read the data store inside a controller. The datastore is already being used by the grid. I want to read the data on a button click and send it to server through AJAX. Later inside server I would retrieve the data and write to XLS. In this case what is the way I can read the data inside the controller?

enter code here

```
Ext.define("MyApp.controller.GridController", {
extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
views: ['performance.grid.PerformanceGrid'],
models: ['GridModel'],
stores: ['GridStore'],
refs : [{
    ref : 'mainTabPanel',
    selector : 'portal > tabpanel'
}],
init : function() {
     this.control({
         'portal toolbar > button[itemId=xls]' : {
             click : this.onAddTab
         },

         'portal toolbar > button[itemId=pdf]' : {
             click : this.onAddPortlet
         }
     });
},
onAddTab : function(btn, e) {
   // I want to read the datastore here and make an AJAX call
 },

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onAddTab: function(btn, e){
   var store = // get the store reference probably doing Ext.getStore('the store');
   var records = store.data.items.map(function(r){ return r.data });

   // send it all to your server as you want to
   // Ext.ajax.Request({
   //    url: 'the url',
   //    data: records,
   //    method: 'POST'
   // });
});
```

I didn´t test it but it have to work.
Good luck!

Comment: One follow up question I have. How can I read the records in server side?

Comment: It depends on the technology you use.

Comment: I am using JAVA. So the AJAX will call a servlet with request and response parameters. So are the record available in request? If yes then how to retrieve it?

Comment: records are available in the request, yes. Java is not my field, sorry.

Comment: I got the data in server side. Then I am writing the same to XLS workbook in response. But there is no prompt for download file. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that process is not the best because you will have 3 payloads (data round trips that doesn't make any sense)

1. Your call your server method to get the data that will be populated into the grid.
2. The JSON object (containing the server data) will then travel again to the server

   > > (**THIS DOESN'T MAKE SENSE TO ME... WHY YOU WANT TO SEND DATA TO SERVER WHEN THE SERVER WAS THE SOURCE??** )
3. The server will process your object from JSON response and then create the document on the fly and send it back to server.

> What I think you should do is the following:

1. Get data from server and bind your grid.
2. Get your `store proxy URL` and parse the method and `extraParams` so you know who served the grid and what you asked to the server.
3. Create a `common method` on server that receives a `method` and an `array of parameters`. Then inside this method make the logic so depending on the method, you call your data Repository (same repository where your first request got the data), process the document and send the file back to server.

This way you should have something like this:

```
webmethod(string method, object[] params) {

   switch(method){
      case "GetTestGridData":
           // here you call your Repository in order to get the same data 
           GeneralRepo repo = new GeneralRepo();
           var data = repo.GetTestGridData(object[0],object[1]); 

         break;
   }

   byte[] fileStream = Reports.Common.Generate(data, ExportType.PDF);
   // response the stream to client...

}
```